# How to add files from another git repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repository that contains my dotfiles. I created it like this:

```sh
cd
git init --bare $HOME/.dotfiles
alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'
dotfiles config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no
echo "alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'" >> $HOME/$ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.sh
```

Basically, it's a little bit modified version (changed alias name, and folder name) of https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles.

I am able to add most of my dotfiles to this repo, like `dotfiles add .tmux.conf`.
However, I found it problematic to add `/home/$USER/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.sh`.
When I do `dotfiles add /home/$USER/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.sh` nothing happens.
I suspect that the problem comes from the fact that `/home/$USER/.oh-my-zsh` is itself a different git repository. Maybe git does not allow me to add a file from another repo to my `~/.dotfiles` repo?

How can I go around that?

Comment: You should not and cannot "get around that" because it will not work. You must decide: do I want all these files in *one* repository, or do I want these files spread across n>1 repositories? Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: If you like, you can write some scripts that figure out which repository some path name goes with. You'll need a bit of trickiness for this case because of the separated `.git` and working tree for the one repository (presumably the others don't have this separation going on).